# How to protect a native function from being overwritten by Google API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have the following native JavaScript function on my web platform:

```
function tag_(t)
{
 return (document.getElementsByTagName(t)) ? document.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;
}
```

There is also the prototype:

```
Object.prototype.tag_ = function(t)
{
 return (this.getElementsByTagName(t)) ? this.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;
}
```

When this function works normally it returns an array of elements from the DOM.

While implementing Google Calendar's API I found that it decided to override this function (not the prototype though). While going through *all* of the raw JavaScript data loaded (with cache disabled as always) I found no mention of the string 'tag_'.

How do I protect a native function on my web platform from being overridden by a third party?

Renaming the function and not using Google's Calendar API are *not* an acceptable answers.

---

Apparently it is possible to "freeze" or "seal" objects:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

This does not seem to work however:

```
Object.freeze(tag_);
```

---

**This question does *not* have a working answer.**

After some research I came across JavaScript proxy (`new Proxy(object_being_watched,function_called_onchange);`) however that does not work with functions, only objects. "There is no such thing as an array in JavaScript! There are only objects!" -- "Functions are not objects." If JavaScript were not designed to be fanatically flexible it would be much more *useful*.

---

Here is a hack work-around though it is very subjective to various conditions.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
 window['tag_'] = function(t)
 {
 return (document.getElementsByTagName(t)) ? document.getElementsByTagName(t) : false;
 }
},500);
```

Comment: Proper scoping?

Comment: Have a look at the "module design pattern"

Answer (score 1):

> This does not seem to work however:

```
   Object.freeze(Object.prototype.tag_);
```

Because `Object.prototype.tag_` is `undefined` and sealing that makes no sense. However you could:

```
  Object.freeze(window);
```

but that would be a bad idea. Instead just do proper scoping:

```
  (function main() {
    function tag_(t) {
       return document.getElementsByTagName(t);
    }
    //...
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps copying the function before loading the Google Calendar API and then once it loads restore it ?